# Ember - import dynamic mixin into the addon

Tags: ember.js, twiddle

Refer this Ember-twiddle demo :-

https://ember-twiddle.com/8ffccad660472740c7484fd36cf53ed6?openFiles=components.dialog-component.js%2C

Comment: If you're asking how to dynamically import a module, you can't. ES6 modules have to be defined statically. (You can use the dynamic loader API, but I'm not sure if Ember supports that.)

Comment: This is not possible at the current time

Comment: If you could describe the problem you are trying to resolve we might be able to come up with an alternative solution

Comment: Hi S.MOHAMED, I see you're still having a problem with this. Do you perhaps want to sign up to the slack community, and we can maybe try flesh out your problem there ? I don't think stackoverflow is the best place to discuss what and why you are trying to do currently. Url for slack, https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/